# How to merge two crawldb in nutch

Tags: search-engine, web-crawler, nutch

Suppose I have two different machines that were crawling two different domains using nutch.

Now I want to merge their crawldb into one. How can I do that ?

I read about it somewhere - Would the command:

```
bin/nutch mergedb <crawldb1> <crawldb2>
```

do what I intend to do ?

Also, in case lets say that one of those crawldb is generated by a site for locally hosted website i.e. say wikipedia crawled itself and stored it as the crawldb1

and some other site lets say stackoverflow also did the same.

In this case can I merge these two crawldb into one but which modifies these in a way to reflect their actual urls not the relative one (I mean the url wrt the new location of the database).

Sorry if I am not very clear in the description. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way to find out if it works, give it a try. And read the manual first, you're missing your merged DB parameter. See http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/bin/nutch%20mergedb

Comment: Sorry but I don't think I still got my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the two db's all URLS in crawldb are always stored in full. Nutch never stores URL relative to anything.

The command you wrote would merge crawldb2 into crawldb1

if you want to merge crawldb localcrawldb and stackoverflowcrawldb

you write

bin/nutch crawldb mergedcrawldb localcrawldb stackoverflowcrawldb

and both crawldbs will be merged into the mergedcrawldb.